# XO Lint Issue Using Promise.map unicorn/no-array-method-this-argument

Tags: javascript, eslint, bluebird

I am using XO for linting my code, and I cannot figure out why this lint error is being reported for the following code...

```js
import Promise from 'bluebird';

const handler = items => {
  return Promise.map(items, item => {
    return Promise.resolve(item);
  });
};

export default handler;
```

When I save this to lint-test.js, and then run the following command...

```sh
npx xo lint-test.js
```

I get this error...

```sh
lint-test.js:4:29
  ✖  4:29  Do not use the this argument in Array#map().  unicorn/no-array-method-this-argument

  1 error
```

The reference for this rule is here... https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-array-method-this-argument.md

I must be missing something simple. I know this is an oversimplified example, but of course, in my real code, I am doing something more interesting with "item".

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method named `.map` and passing more than one argument - this is all the rule is looking for. The ESlint rule doesn't understand that `Promise` is the bluebird library but thinks it's an array, and that you're calling the [*Array* `map` method, where the second parameter is for the `this` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) (and which the warning says you shouldn't use).

It's a false positive.

Remove the rule from your settings, ignore it for that line, or make a PR to add an exception for `Promise` as the receiver of the method call.